# How to use AddHandler to add event handler for a click event on a button in WPF

Tags: wpf, event-handling

Hey collective brain,

So I need to add some additional click behavior to an existing button of a control whose click event, i assume, is handled somewhere in its encapsulated code. So I am using AddHandler() on the button, which is a CalendarDayButton, I can't seem to find a handler for click event. For the first argument of the AddHandler, I used ButtonBase.ClickEvent, and for the second I just used new EventHandler(button_click), and the third is "true". And then I get the "Handler type is mismatched." exception. Any input on this would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that, in WPF, [ButtonBase.Click](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.buttonbase.click.aspx#Y0) is a [RoutedEventHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.routedeventhandler.aspx).  You need to add an appropriate delegate (not `EventHandler`, but one that implements `RoutedEventHandler`).